# Ember.js hasMany as list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following two models:

```
App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And:

```
App.Activity = DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany('child',{async:true}),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I want to use checkboxes to choose between the existing children, for the **hasMany** relation.

For example, I have these three children:

```
App.Child.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Brian' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Michael' },
  { id: 3, name: 'James' }
];
```

The user should be able to use checkboxes, while creating or editing an activity, for choosing which children, to add to the **hasMany** relation.

I've created a JSFiddle to illustrate my question: http://jsfiddle.net/Dd6Wh/. Click 'Create a new activity' to see what I'm trying to do.

Basically it's the same as **Ember.Select [ ... ] multiple="true"**, but for checkboxes.

What's the correct approach for something like this with Ember.js?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an `itemController` in your `each` view helper to manage the selection. In the code below I created one called `ChildController`:

```
App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
    selected: function() {
        var activity = this.get('content');
        var children = this.get('parentController.children');
        return children.contains(activity);
    }.property(),
    selectedChanged: function() {
        var activity = this.get('content');
        var children = this.get('parentController.children');
        if (this.get('selected')) {                                    
            children.pushObject(activity);            
        } else {                                    
            children.removeObject(activity);                                                    
        }        
    }.observes('selected')
});
```

With a itemController you can expose some properties and logics, without add it directlly to your models. In that case the `selected` computed property and the `selectedChanged` observer.

In your template, you can bind the selection using `checkedBinding="selected"`. Because the itemController proxy each model, the `selected` property of the itemcontroller will be used, and the `{{name}}` binding, will lookup the name property of the model:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="activities/new">
    <h1>Create a new activity</h1>

    {{#each childList itemController="child"}}
        <label>
            {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
            {{name}}
        </label><br />
    {{/each}}
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
    <button {{action create}}>Create</button>
</script>
```

The same aproach in edit template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="activities/edit">
    <h1>Edit an activity</h1>

    {{#each childList itemController="child"}}
        <label>
            {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
            {{name}}
        </label><br />
    {{/each}}
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
    <button {{action update}}>Update</button>
</script>
```

This is a fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8EjRk/

**Component version**

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/checkbox-select">
    {{#each elements itemController="checkboxItem"}}
        <label>            
            {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
            {{label}}
        </label><br />
    {{/each}}    
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
App.CheckboxSelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({   
    /* The property to be used as label */
    labelPath: null,
    /* The model */
    model: null,
    /* The has many property from the model */
    propertyPath: null,
    /* All possible elements, to be selected */
    elements: null,
    elementsOfProperty: function() {
        return this.get('model.' + this.get('propertyPath'));
    }.property()
});

App.CheckboxItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
    selected: function() {        
        var activity = this.get('content');
        var children = this.get('parentController.elementsOfProperty');        
        return children.contains(activity);
    }.property(),
    label: function() {    
        return this.get('model.' + this.get('parentController.labelPath'));
    }.property(),
    selectedChanged: function() {
        var activity = this.get('content');
        var children = this.get('parentController.elementsOfProperty');
        if (this.get('selected')) {                                    
            children.pushObject(activity);            
        } else {                                    
            children.removeObject(activity);                                                    
        }        
    }.observes('selected')
});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mgLr8/14/

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly! Would it be possible to build this as a reusable component or view? My model has multiple 'hasMany' relations, so it would be great, if I didnt have to copy the code multiple times.

Comment: I extracted to an ember component, with some customizable properties. Please give a look http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/mgLr8/.